# Formatting within Entity Framework Where Clause

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query on my db context

```
Dim query = (
    From n In db.tblNews
    Join nc In db.tblNewsCategories On n.CatID Equals nc.CategoryID
    Order By n.DateEntered Descending
    Select New With {
      .NewsID = n.NewsID,
      .Title = n.Title,
      .NewsText = n.NewsText,
      .isPublished = n.isPublished,
      .CatID = n.CatID,
      .CategoryName = nc.CategoryName,
      .DateEntered = n.DateEntered,
      .ReadCount = n.ReadCount,
      .DatePublished = n.DatePublish
       }
    )
```

Then, according to the values in my DropDownListBox, I apply a WHERE clause to filter data later in the code such as;

```
If sDate <> "" Then
    query = query.Where(Function(n) n.DateEntered = sDate)
End If
```

Now, sDate comes in the format of `2013-06-18` and in the db the corresponding `DateTime` field is in the format of `2013-06-18 16:41:33.973` hence, the query returns zero results.

I have tried to do the following:

```
If sDate <> "" Then
    query = query.Where(Function(n) String.Format(n.DateEntered, {0:yyyy-MM-dd}) = sDate)
End If
```

which gave me the error:
*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression*

I also do not want to format the date in my select since, I want the output to be exactly the same as with the database.

How can I format the date in my query's where clause? If I can't is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim dateStart = DateTime.Parse(sDate)
Dim dateEnd = date.AddDays(1)
query = query.Where(Function(n) n.DateEntered >= dateStart And n.DateEntered < dateEnd)
```

Basically, this will check if `DateEntered` is between `sDate`, which is just the date at midnight, and midnight the next day.

Comment: This is less than ideal because it requires 2 comparisons.

Comment: If you're comparing a bare date with a date/time, I think you have to do it this way using LINQ.

Comment: You should still be able to grab the Date portion of the DateTime and compare it with the date.  In .Net, a Date is essentially a DateTime with default values for the Time portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the format of your sDate variable (or at least make a copy of it in the new format) and compare that against what is in your LINQ query.  LINQ doesn't understand .ToString, and you are trying to compare a String value against a Date or DateTime value.  VB is really bad about hiding this kind of stuff from you so you don't really know what you are doing wrong.

Assuming that your .DateEntered values in your database are Date type (and not DateTime), try this:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sDate) Then
    Dim someDate As Date = DateTime.Parse(sDate).Date
    query = query.Where(Function(n) n.DateEntered = someDate)
End If
```

EDIT:  Try this one if it is DateTime

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sDate) Then
    Dim someDate As Date = DateTime.Parse(sDate).Date
    query = query.Where(Function(n) n.DateEntered.Date = someDate)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks @Douglas but the date values are of DateTime2 data type. Otherwise, I wouldn't have a problem with the equality operation (I guess?).

Comment: Try it now and let me know if it works.  The edit I made will work, as long as the DateTime values in your database are not nullable.  If they are, you will need to compare them with n.DateEntered.Value.Date instead.